# Get all Trello cards in a specific list from all boards in an organization sorted by member

Tags: api, trello

I am quite new to the Trello API and I am looking for a good solution for an issue I am having.

**Issue**

We have an organization with quite some boards.

- All boards are organization visible
- Some boards also include members who are not member of the organization.
- Lists inside a board have specific names, like "To Do", "In Progress" etc.

We have a status screen where we would like to display all cards from a specific list inside the organization. These cards should be sorted by member, even for the members not in our organization.

A lot of this information is dynamic, like members, cards and boards.

**What I am doing now**

At the moment I have only found a solution where we make a lot of requests to the API, which of course has a [limit](http://help.trello.com/article/838-api-rate-limits).

1. At first we are going through all boards inside the organization to get the board id's.
2. Then we are looping through these id's to get all members inside all boards. This is needed because some board-members are not member of the organization. Duplicates are removed.
3. When this is done, we found 2 different ways to get the cards. (1) Go through `members/[idMember or username]/cards`. here we can't get the list name. (2) Go through `boards/[board_id]/lists`, here we can't get the member name.

Because we can't get all information in a single or just a few requests this process is very slow and even unstable because of the limit in the API.

Is there anyone with a good/better solution? In a perfect world I'd like to have a single request like this:

`GET /1/organizations/[idOrg or name]/boards` where we can send in arguments to get all cards, all members and all lists.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `boards/[board_id]/lists` and compare the ids of the members on each card to the member data you already have?

Comment: Well, of course this is possible. I am just wondering if there is a better way to avoid making too many requests at the same time.